# GA4 event page path debug tests fine, but the GA4 event is not recording

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Google Tag Manager, I've created a GA4 event, `ids2_verify_email`, that fires on a page view trigger where the page path contains `verify-email` and `Page is Reloaded CJS` equals `false`.

`Page is Reloaded CJS` is a user-defined variable with custom JS:

```
function() {
  return performance.navigation.type == 0 ? false: true;
}
```

(so that we don't create the event again on a page reload, learned from [this article](https://measureschool.com/how-to-prevent-tags-from-firing-after-a-page-reload-with-google-tag-manager/))

These GTM changes were published seven days ago.

The developer team know that users have been verifying their email and hitting the URL that contains `verify-email` in the last seven days.

Our [Amplitude](https://amplitude.com/) report shows around 250 users and developers hitting the following:

- au.example.com/verify-email?xxx
- uk.example.com/verify-email?xxx
- us.example.com/verify-email?xxx

However, GA4 shows no instance of the `ids2_verify_email` event in the last seven days.

GA4 is recording plenty of other events from our website.

If I debug the `ids2_verify_email` GA4 tag in GTM and load our email verification URL, the tag shows as fired and `ids2_verify_email` displays in the GA4 real-time report.

Why would the `ids2_verify_email` event not show in the GA4 Engagement > Events report for the last seven days?

Thoughts appreciated.